# Listening to icecast stream

Tags: html, icecast, audio-player

I have set up an Icecast server on a Vagrant box and I wonder how I can listen to a stream on a specific mountpoint with a basic HTML5 audio player?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your stream URL in your browser like this:

`http://<YOUR_SERVER_IP>:<SERVER_PORT>/<MOUNT_POINT>`

If you want to use a web  player - try `jPlayer` or `SoundManager2`

Answer (score 0):

An example of usage would be the icecast internet station:
  http://relay-nyc.gameowls.com:8000/all.ogg

Note their use of port 8000.

Having run an icecast station for some time, I can attest to the following:
Chrome, circa 2016, worked correctly.  It streamed song after song, not stopping.

Firefox, circa 2016, did not work correctly.  Firefox would stream 1 song and stop.

Chrome, prior some build, did not work correctly.  Old versions of Chrome would stream 1 song and stop.  Fresh Ubuntu 12 installs, actually their default Chromium versions, would have this problem of streaming 1 song and stopping.  An update of Chromium would fix the issue.

The latest Chromium on Linux works correctly: streams song after song.
The latest Chrome on an Android phone works correctly.